# How to sum values of rows based on condition within each row?

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please help me with a better solution on summarizing data based on conditions in separate rows.

I have to group by the deal with a custom logic on amount column. Add Investment and Capital and subtract borrow and interest amounts from that, this should happen only if currency key matches else create a new column with above logic considering currencies separately and not mixing the amounts of different currencies. One more condition to consider is, do this computation only if all 4 types of flows are present.

For example my data is

```py
   Deal        Flow  Amount Currency
0     1  Investment     100      USD
1     1      Borrow      10      USD
2     1    Interest       5      USD
3     1     Capital      50      EUR
4     2  Investment     100      USD
5     2      Borrow      10      USD
6     2    Interest       5      USD
7     2     Capital      50      USD
8     3  Investment     100      USD
9     3      Borrow      10      EUR
10    3    Interest       5      USD
11    4  Investment     100      USD
12    4      Borrow      10      EUR
13    4    Interest       5      USD
14    4     Capital      50      USD
```

Expected output would be

```
  Deal  Amount Currency  Amount Currency
0    1      85      USD    50.0      EUR
1    2     135      USD     NaN     None
2    4     145      USD   -10.0      EUR
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you need to use pandas for this task? It looks to me like there are ways to organize these rows using only lists and dictionaries and performing the calculations according to the conditions that you describe.

Comment: I have carefully computed each column  ```df.pivot(['Deal'], ['Flow', 'Currency']).fillna(0)[('Amount', 'Investment', 'USD')].sub(df.pivot(['Deal'], ['Flow', 'Currency']).fillna(0)[('Amount', 'Borrow', 'USD')])``` while evaluating flow count using  ```df.groupby(['Deal'])['Deal'].count()``` and removing those rows with less than 4 count.

Comment: Map amount to negative values for borrow and interest, then groupby deal AND currency, and sum the new amount.

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
dict = {
    'Deal' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'Flow' : ['Investment', 'Borrow', 'Interest', 'Capital', 'Investment', 'Borrow', 'Interest', 'Capital', 'Investment',
           'Borrow', 'Interest', 'Investment', 'Borrow', 'Interest', 'Capital'],
    'Amount' : [100, 10 ,5 ,50 ,100 ,10 ,5 ,50 ,100 ,10 ,5 ,100 ,10 ,5 ,50 ],
    'Currency' : ['USD' ,'USD' ,'USD' ,'EUR' ,'USD' ,'USD' ,'USD' ,'USD' ,'USD' ,'EUR' ,'USD' ,'USD' ,'EUR' ,'USD' ,'USD']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Create new column to differentiate negative amount based on flow.

```
df['New_Amount'] = df.apply(lambda x : -1 * x['Amount'] if x['Flow'] in ['Borrow', 'Interest'] else x['Amount'], axis=1)
```

Created list of deal where count of flow is 4 and then filter dataframe

```
dealed_df = df.groupby('Deal').agg({'Flow':'count'}).reset_index()
list_deal = dealed_df[dealed_df['Flow']==4]['Deal'].to_list()
filtered_df = df[df['Deal'].isin(list_deal)]
```

And then group by dataframe based on deal to sum new_amount

```
filtered_df.groupby(['Deal', 'Currency']).agg({'New_Amount':'sum'}).reset_index().pivot(index='Deal', columns='Currency', values='New_Amount').reset_index()
```

Result

```
Currency    Deal    EUR     USD
0           1       50.0    85.0
1           2       NaN     135.0
2           4       -10.0   145.0
```